# passing '&' in add_filter return function of wordpress

Tags: wordpress, add-filter

I have below line in my return function of `add_filter` in wordpress.

```
jQuery.ajax({
....ajax rest code here...
data: 'url='+url+'&un=0&pretty=1&mega=0&click=true',
...ajax rest code here..
});
```

but in content page of view source, it is available as :-

```
jQuery.ajax({
....ajax rest code...
data: 'url='+url+'&#038;un=0&#038;pretty=1&#038;mega=0&#038;click=true',
...ajax rest code..
});
```

But my requirement is to pass it as it is with '&' and not any special character of html.

How can this be achived.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse it when you are receiving the data.
PHP

```
str_replace("&#038", "&", $_GET['URL']);
```

The ampersand (&) is a special character in URLs it means that it is beginning a new variable so it must be properly encoded or it will mess with the variables being passed.

Comment: how would i do that in wordpress, i am just learning to create plugin in wordpress

Comment: WordPress/Wordpress Plugins are written in PHP.  Do you have some source so I can see what you're trying to achieve.